# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" - Property Wrapper in Swift and XCode 14

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture, xcode14

I'm getting an error with the following code in Swift. The code is fine if I do not use a property wrapper. I get `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` in XCode 14.

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct Clamping<Value: Comparable> {
    var value: Value
    let range: ClosedRange<Value>
    

    public init(wrappedValue value: Value, _ range: ClosedRange<Value>) {
        self.value = min(max(range.lowerBound, value), range.upperBound)
        self.range = range
    }

    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value }
        set { value = min(max(range.lowerBound, newValue), range.upperBound) }
    }
}

var dragGesture: some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            @Clamping(0...1) var progress: CGFloat = (120 + value.translation.width) / 120
            updateSampleView(progress: progress)
        }
}

func updateSampleView(progress:CGFloat) {
    print(progress)
}
```

Comment: I get other errors with your code: "Cannot find 'updateSampleView' in scope" and if I disable that line, then error is "error: closure captures '_progress' before it is declared". So can you please post the code that reproduces your pbolem, and also specify which line gives you that error.

Comment: I updated it. 'updateSampleView' function can be any function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a property wrapper can only be used as an property - variable that’s stored as part of an instance of a particular class or structure. A variable inside a block of code is not a property, thus it will not work inside onChanged().

A code like this probably what you are looking for:

```
extension Comparable {
    func clamped(to range: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
        return min(max(range.lowerBound, self), range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var progress: CGFloat = ((120 + value.translation.width) / 120).clamped(to: 0...1)
```